# How do you use mysql join to filter out an entire row?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I want to run a query that selects the latest question a user hasn't answered from 2 separate tables. This is what I came up with:

```
SELECT Q.question_id, Q.question, S.user_id, S.question_id 
FROM questions Q inner join answers S on Q.question_id=S.question_id 
WHERE S.user_id != '$userID'
```

This indeed does filter out the rows where the user has answered a specific question but unfortunately if another user answers the same question it still returns that question. I want to eliminate the question being returned all together if the user hasn't answered.

Suggestions/ideas are welcome, thanks.

Comment: Your wording makes it ambiguous as to what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to filter out the questions the user has answered, or not answered?

Comment: do you want the latest unanswered question?

Comment: yes. i want to select the latest unanswered question for that particular user logged in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Select all questions which have not been answered by `$userId`":

```
SELECT Q.question_id, Q.question
FROM questions Q 
WHERE 
    Q.question_id NOT IN (
         /* Select all questions's ids, which have been answered by $userId */
         SELECT `question_id` 
         FROM `answer` 
         WHERE `answer`.`user_id` = '$userId'
    )
```

Comment: works perfect. thanks so much for understanding exactly what I was looking for and breaking it down making it a lot more simple. kudos to you

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too unclear and it lacks information. You need to include the schema of your tables, sample records, and desired output to make it more clear. I think you want to select questions that is not yet answered: ***I want to run a query that selects the latest question a user hasn't answered...*** The statement will merely look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Questions WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(user_id) = 0;
```

`CHAR_LENGTH` gets the length of the string with in a column. It return `ZERO` when the field is empty.

Comment: Can you explain the reason for using `CHAR_LENGTH`? I would assume `user_id` to be of type `INTEGER`, not `VARCHAR`, so calling `CHAR_LENGTH` will convert the `user_id` to a string and then count it's length, i.e. `SELECT CHAR_LENGTH(10)` outputs `2`. Assuming the table `question` had a column `user_id` that was empty if the question was not answered, why would you use an empty `VARCHAR` instead of `NULL` to represent this?

Answer (score 1):

A left join might be more appropriate in this case:

```
SELECT Q.question_id, Q.question, S.user_id, S.question_id 
FROM questions Q 
LEFT JOIN answers S on Q.question_id=S.question_id AND S.user_id = '$userID'
WHERE s.user_id IS NULL
```

This should return all entries from table Q that have no matching records in table S.

Comment: `'$userID'` can never be `NULL`.

Comment: @johntotetwoo It's a `LEFT JOIN`. If no join partner is found, `s.user_id` will be `NULL`. But the condition doesn't make sense, as `user_id` cannot be `$userId` **and** `NULL` at the same time. So the condition is equivalent to `WHERE FALSE`.

Comment: look at this: `WHERE S.user_id = '$userID'` **AND** `s.user_id IS NULL`. Can you possibly condition the field with two values? I think it's not possible.

Comment: @johntotetwoo Yes you are right. I read your comment wrong! ;-)

Comment: My bad, please ignore this answer. I was too focused on trying to avoid the sub query.

Comment: This should make more sense now

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT Q.question_id, Q.question, S.user_id, S.question_id 
FROM questions Q
JOIN answers S ON Q.question_id=S.question_id 
WHERE 
    S.user_id NOT IN (
         SELECT user_id 
         FROM answers 
         WHERE question_id = Q.question_id
    )
    AND S.user_id = '$userID'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to run 2 separate query's i think because join is meant for 2 tables with unique attributes.. so you couldn't match up a bunch of answers with 1 question on a join.

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from `answers` where `user_id` = '$bar'");

while ($rslt = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);) {
    $in_clause .= $rslt['question_id'].',';
}
$in_clause = substr($in_clause,0,-1);
$next_query = mysql_query("select * from `questions` where `question_id` !in(".$in_clause.")");
```